# My Google Analytics account will not work with Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I am currently setting up a wordpress site and am trying to add Google Analytics on the site.

To add the the analytics I copied and pasted the code into `footer.php`. The code appears on all the pages now, but when I look at my Google account no visitors have been registered.

I immediately visited the site via my mobile and viewed the live update tab, my visit was not registered. I also visited a few hours later without success.

Can anyone advise what I am missing/have done wrong?

I have tried to use the plugin which you can download too but once again I don't get any information on my account

Comment: usually you get updates after 24hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: [where to put google analytics code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619950/where-to-put-google-analytics-code)

And here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/installing-google-analytics-5

Try putting the code before the closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: Hi, it seems that it must take a little time for the thing to work. I have checked about 24 hours after putting the cod in and it has registered my visit....i assume it was my visit

Comment: You can check the geographical data to be more sure. Also, as far as I know, it's still best practice to put it where Google / WordPress suggest, so, you might want to consider that and maybe approve the answer so nobody else answers? Either way, glad it's working.

Comment: Great advice. I wasn't aware that there was a specified place. At the moment is at the bottom on the footer. I will look into that posted link. Thanks

Comment: The guidelines seem to be at the bottom of the head tag, best get it moved.