# google blogger: how to replace old analytics snippet with new asynchronous snippet?

Tags: google-analytics, blogger

I have a Google Analytics account and I need to use the new asynchronous snippet in my blogger blog. According to documentation, I should insert GA `<script>` tag to the bottom of the `<head>` section.

In my blogger html template, the `<body>` section ends with this:

```
  </div>
  </div>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.className = document.body.className.replace(&#39;loading&#39;, &#39;&#39;);
      }, 10);
  </script>
  <b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/>
</body>
```

So this is the old snippet and should be disabled, yes?

Well, I commented the line `<b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/>` and scrolled up to the `<head>` section. It ends like this:

```
      #layout .region-inner {
        min-width: 0;
        width: auto;
      }
      ]]>
    </b:template-skin>
  </head>
```

So I inserted the Google Analytics `<script>` tag just before the `</head>`. But it doesn't upload and it says that I have an error.

So, how to do it?

Comment: Ok, before anyone else works on this: the problem was the commenting the old GA code. Don't comment, just delete, then it works. Btw, commenting was done like this:

`<!--<b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/> -->`

  so this should be ok, but wasn't. But I can't answer my own question

Comment: can't really answer for sure since no access and all, but your blog template script probably works by scraping your page for that tag and replacing it with real html code.  IOW your page code goes through a template system (which does not render html) and then sends to browser to be rendered.  Your template system *probably* has some kind of commenting syntax to use, so that it will know to ignore things; look at your template system's documentation, or look through your code for possible other examples

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173571/should-i-put-the-google-analytics-js-in-the-head-or-at-the-end-of-body. Its main answers appear to have links containing an answer to this question too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer to my question is that the error I was getting yesterday has not occurred today, when I made a test one more time. So basically there is no issue at all: either deleting or commenting the old GA snippet should work.